# How to unit test services.AddHttpClient() registration in dotnet core V2.2

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am working on Web API dotnet core V2.2 project. I have the below named client registered in my Startup.cs file. I want to do unit testing using NSubstitute to make may code coverage for the below method. Can someone help me on this. Thanks in advance.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddHttpClient("myapi", (serviceProvider, client) = >{
    var config = serviceProvider.GetService < IConfiguration > ();
    client.BaseAddress = new URI(config["mybaseURL"]);
});
```

}

Comment: Create the necessary dependencies, invoke the method under test and try to resolve the named client. verify that it has the desired properties.

Answer (score 0):

I am too late to answer this.
You can try this:

```
//Arrange
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.ConfigureServices();
//Act
var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory = provider.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();


var httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("myapi");

Assert.NotNull(httpClient);
//Write other Asserts ex: check the base address
```